# Coldfusion (Solr) search behavior

Tags: coldfusion, solr, cfquery, cfsearch, cfindex

I have this "indexer" template:

```
<cfquery name="LOCAL.modelli" datasource="xxx">
    SELECT id, name, brand FROM products 
</cfquery>
<cfindex action="refresh" 
         collection="mycoll"
         key="id"
         type="custom"
         title="nome"
         query="LOCAL.modelli"
         body="nome" />
```

And I am using this code for searching ( #t# is coming from search form field ) :

```
<cfsearch collection="mycoll" name="LOCAL.ricerca" criteria="#t#" status="LOCAL.searchStatus" suggestions="always" />
```

Imagine I have this "products" table in DB:

ID    |    Name  |

1     |  FRAG 13 |

2     | FOOBAR   |

3     | FROGSKIN |

Searching "frog" DOES NOT FIND "Frogskin" !

Instead, it suggests "frag".

Is this behavior normal? Can you explain it to me?

How can I make my search engine find "frogskin", with "frog" as a criteria? (I'd like to avoid doing a SQL query to "products" to enhance results) .

Thank you.

Comment: where are you using Solr here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a wildcard, the engine will look for the exact word, "frog"

You need to use a wildcard `?` or `*`.  Note that SOLR does not support leading wildcards so
`*frog` would not find `bullfrog` but `frog*` should find `frogskin`

see [Solr search examples](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS82937B1B-240F-4850-B376-5FD9F911E5E5.html) for more information on searching with SOLR and ColdFusion.